# How do you calculate the standard error of a factor in the slope and intercept of a linear model?

Tags: r, standard-error, linear

I have derived a linear equation to describe an experiment.

```
y = slope . x + intercept
```

where `slope = a / (b.d)`
where `intercept = (e + f.g) / (b.d)`

In R I have found the standard error of the confidence interval for the slope and the intercept.

'b' and 'g' are constants.

'a' and 'f' are the variables with standard errors for which I am looking.

There is currently literature data for 'd' to eliminate there being three factors. So, 'd' can be considered as a constant.

To find the standard error for 'a' I took the variance of the intercept and used the equation:

```
var(slope) = (1/(b.d))^2 . var(a)

=> var(slope) / (1/(b.d))^2 =  var(a)
```

Is this the correct method?

For calculating the variance of 'f'

```
(e + f.g) / (b.d)

= (e / (b.d)) + (g / (b.d)) . f



=> var(intercept) =  var((e / (b.d)) + (g / (b.d)) . f)

var(intercept) =  var(0 + (g / (b.d))^2 . var(f))
```

Is this correct?

Comment: Is $e$ a constant? Are you sure $d$ is constant during your experiment?

Comment: e is a constant. 'd' has been provided by other experiments.

Comment: The variances of estimators of slope and intercept are the variances of estimators of constants. Are $a$ and $f$ functions of $x$?

Comment: ??? Sorry, I'm not quite sure what you are asking. The experiment has been repeated at changing concentrations of x and the value for y has been recorded. A slope and an intercept parameter and the standard error was calculated in R. All coefficients are known constants except 'a' and 'f'. For the equation: http://i.imgur.com/Ra2JZvX.png?1

Comment: Okay. Let me rephrase my question. When you say "constants", do you mean that you know their value? and when you say "variables" for $a$ and $f$, do you mean that you do not know their value and you assume that they are unknown constants?

Comment: In that case, your formulas are good. Your last formula is bad written, it is : $var(intercept) =  (g / (b.d))^2 . var(f)$

Comment: Ok. I was hoping that I made a mistake. I just re-did the calculation and the variance is x10^15. Oh. Well. Back to the drawing board it is.